# Load and access all images on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where the menu buttons(which are images) are white but i want them to turn red on hover and back to white onmouseout. So i have the corresponding red menu buttons. So if the white button is motors1.jpg, the red button is motors2.jpg hence the JQuery code below algorithm.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/home1.gif"/></td>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/motors1.gif"/></td>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/about_us1.gif"/></td>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/media1.gif"/></td>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/forums1.gif"/></td>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/dealers1.gif"/></td>
<td><img class="navimg" src="images/whats_new1.gif"/></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

The Jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.navimg').mouseover(function(){
    source=$(this).attr('src').replace('1','2');
    $(this).attr('src',source);

   }).mouseout(function(){
    source= source.replace('2','1');
    $(this).attr('src',source);
   });

});
```

I have used an external CSS stylesheet for positioning

```
                          .navimg{
                         width: 125.5px;
                         height: 34px;
                                  }
```

So the question: I noticed that there is a lag when the page is first loaded for the white buttons to change to the red ones. I assume the lag is because the red buttons were not loaded on page load(therefore are not in the browser cache) and hence the jquery code reloads them. So any way to solve this by maybe loading them as hidden inputs, loading them to the browser cache would be appreciated or any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use image sprites [source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

You will have for one menu button one image file that will be contains white and red images, so you need only change `background-position` on hover action. It's very fast, images load fully and you needn't use some javascripts, only CSS
.

Answer (score 2):

Using a sprite is the best solution.

However if this is not possible for you, then you can preload images by using the following JavaScript method (taken from Dreamweaver).

**Add the following just after your html tag.**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
</script>
```

Add the following property to your body tag:

```
onload="MM_preloadImages('path of image goes here')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by joining motor1.gif and motors2.gif to become motors.gif.

If you made one image with the white image at the top, and the red image at the bottom, then your `mouseover/mouseout` (ps. check out `hover`) just needs to change the image offset, no pre-loading required.

Comment: What do you mean by joining the images together?...that's like photoshop layers. You can't do that with picture formats.